# The photoelectric effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Are there any interactions such as photoelectric effect noted with the photons reaching us from distant galaxies, just as we observe from the sun rays?

Comment: Sure, whenever you take an astronomical photo with a digital camera, you're demonstrating the photoelectric effect with photons from those distant stars & galaxies.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Not strictly true. You are not using the photoelectric effect as the excited electrons never leave the solid state chip, until read out. If it were the PE, there wouldn't be such a thing as optical and infrared CCDs.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape, The phenomenon of optical absorption promoting electrons between bands in a semiconductor is also called the photoelectric effect, and it demonstrates many of the same behaviors as the photoelectric effect that produces free electrons from metals.